# How to write a propper console handler in Java?

Tags: java, logging, console, console-application

I'm trying to write a propper console handler for my Java application so that I can handle commands while the application is running in the background. My problem is, that I don't know how to put what the user wrote on the end of the console like you see in every other console application.

Imagine we have something like this

```
[24.02.2022 00:11:08 FINE]: Logger initialized!
[24.02.2022 00:11:08 INFO]: Logger initialized!
[24.02.2022 00:11:08 INFO]: Logger initialized! AGAIN
>
```

Now I write for example "help" to get the menu from the console but in the same moment the console prints out something new and just puts the message behind what I just wrote, when I continue writing it looks all really messed up.

```
[24.02.2022 00:11:08 FINE]: Logger initialized!
[24.02.2022 00:11:08 INFO]: Logger initialized!
[24.02.2022 00:11:08 INFO]: Logger initialized! AGAIN
> he
[24.02.2022 00:11:08 INFO]: Logger initialized! AGAIN
> lp
```

Or I didn't sent the command yet. Of course I'm getting a smililar outcome.

Here my handler:

```java
 @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        System.out.print("\b\b");
        System.out.print(this.getFormatter().format(record));
        System.out.print(YukiLogFormatter.ANSI_RESET + "> ");
    }
```

The "\b\b" is to remove the "> " which should indicate that you can write a command here.

Comment: If the background process can write to the console at any time, then you cannot avoid this.  In ancient mainframe console systems, where the console was both a printed continuous log _and_ the operator's input device, there was a "REQUEST" button which the operator had to press in order to type something in.  That button opened the console for input, blocking any pending output.

Comment: A "proper" console handler would have a window akin to the consoles you see in Chat applications (or Javascript debuggers).  An input area where you type and an output area where the system writes messages.

Comment: Can't I just read what the user already typed, delete everything the user wrote including "> ", print the output and put anything back in place?

Comment: Problem with this is, that this application runns on linux without a user interface, so I don't really have that. If there is a way to imitate that in console based enviroments please tell me. @JimGarrison

Comment: That's really not possible without low-level hardware control of the terminal.  This is not something you can accomplish in Java.

Comment: But wait @JimGarrison how do minecraft servers (which run on java) accomplish that? They don't have this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242344/discussion-between-noah-till-and-jim-garrison).

Comment: It's not ALL Java. There's quite a bit of C++ and C# as well.

Comment: guess I'll be using log4j than. Thanks for your help